# Can I use regex in SharePoint GetListItems web service

Tags: web-services

I need to list all the files located in one document library that match a specific naming convention: The documents to retrieve are all in the form 'Report xxxx-xx-xx'.

I have to use the GetListItems web service.

Is there a way to collect all these documents in one call? How to write the 'where' section in the query part?
Can I use some regex in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a CAML query to the GetListItems service. CAML doesn't support regex, but it does have operators for BeginsWith and Contains.

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <BeginsWith>
         <FieldRef Name="Title" />
         <Value Type="Text">Report</Value>
      </BeginsWith>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

To do full regex style matching and get exactly what you want, you would then have to filter the result set on the client side using Javascript's regex.

Comment: I don't really understand what CAML is really but to my perspective, it's only a problem of what SharePoint can interpret in the value.  
---


Example:      
    `<Value Type="Text">Report (\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)</Value>`

Comment: It interprets what you put in. You could build up a more complicated expression with Ands and Ors to make sure it contains a - and digits 0-9 if that helps you narrow it down further, but it doesn't support regex, it doesn't even support a concept of "NotContains".

Comment: For BeginsWith, Contains, it will ultimately convert it to an SQL "LIKE" expression, but it will mess with any wildcards you put in. So Contains [0-9]-[0-9] gets changed to LIKE N'%[[]0-9]-[[]0-9]%'

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could add a [Calculated Column](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/calculate-data-in-lists-or-libraries-HA010105480.aspx) on your document library, that performs a string manipulation and/or test operation on your title text, and returns eg something that can then easily be picked up in your where clause?

This might help limit the result set at the server side...

`=IF(LEFT([TitleColumn],7)="Report ", if(ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(RIGHT([TitleColumn],10))), "TRUE", "FALSE"), "FALSE")`

Refer to [Microsoft's Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) for what's available in calculated columns.

Comment: A good idea, I can re-use somewhere else but this is too complicated in this case. if I have to build a calculated column for each different request...

Comment: @AlbanSoupper You stated _The documents to retrieve are all in the form 'Report xxxx-xx-xx'_ This will identify _all_ of those documents in that format (I've assumed `xxxx-xx-xx` is a datestamp).  And then a single where clause to filter on just the result of this column.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: It's correct :)

Comment: @AlbanSoupper so since you _need to list all the files located in **one** document library_, you only need to add **one** column.